# heap space error while executing a query which returns a lot of data

Tags: hibernate

I have a query which returns a lot of data is there a way how can I avoid heap space error

How can I add paging on it or some other sort of mechanism for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way (assuming you want to create criteria for the class Cat:

```
Session sessione = sf.getCurrentSession();
Criteria crit = sessione.createCriteria(Cat.class);
crit.setFirstResult(currentPage);
crit.setMaxResults(maxNumber);
return crit.list();
```

Angelo